# Call an EventHandler from another Method

Tags: c#, .net

How can I call the following method from another method on same code behind page?

```
protected void CustomValidatorDelLN_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        bool is_valid = txtDeliveryLastName.Text != "";
        txtDeliveryLastName.BackColor = is_valid ? System.Drawing.Color.White : System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
        args.IsValid = is_valid;
    }
```

I don't know how to handle the `(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)` bit. I call `CustomValidatorDelLN_ServerValidate();` What do I put inside the brackets?

Comment: Calling event handlers from other methods is rather strange... what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Paolo Tedesco I've a set of custom validators which get called onSubmit. However the form has a means of copying address details from one section to another and for completeness it woulld be ideal to call the custom validators during that time as well. I could copy all the validation to the copy event but it's duplicating code which isn't a good thing! I'm new to .net so  bit vage on whats the best action to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something Like this can work...

```
    protected void CustomValidatorDelLN_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {

        args.IsValid = isValid();
    }


protected bool isValid()
{

    bool is_valid = txtDeliveryLastName.Text != "";
        txtDeliveryLastName.BackColor = is_valid ? System.Drawing.Color.White : System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
    return is_valid;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you're not directly referencing the `sender`, and you're not properly using the `ServerValidateEventArgs`, you can shortcut things a bit:

```
var args = new ServerValidateEventArgs(String.Empty, false);
CustomValidatorDelLN_ServerValidate(null, args);
```

I wouldn't do that though. I would suggest a refactor. Calling an Event Handler from other code really doesn't make sense. You could easily pull out the validation logic and put it in a separate method. You could then use that new method from both spots in your code:

```
// You can call this method from both places
protected bool ValidateLastName()
{
    bool isValid = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDeliveryLastName.Text);
    txtDeliveryLastName.BackColor = isValid ? Color.White : Color.LightPink;
    return isValid;
}

// This would be the modified Event Handler
protected void CustomValidatorDelLN_ServerValidate(object sender,
    ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = ValidateLastName();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Extract that validation logic to another method

```
public bool CheckValidity()
{
        bool is_valid = txtDeliveryLastName.Text != "";
        txtDeliveryLastName.BackColor = is_valid ? System.Drawing.Color.White : System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
        return is_valid;
}
```

And use it

```
protected void CustomValidatorDelLN_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = CheckValidity();
    }
```

Now call `CheckValidity()` from anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking out another method:

```
private bool ValidateDeliveryLastName()
    {
        bool is_valid = txtDeliveryLastName.Text != "";
        txtDeliveryLastName.BackColor = is_valid ? System.Drawing.Color.White : System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
        return is_valid;
    }
```

then use the call

```
protected void CustomValidatorDelLN_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = ValidateDeliveryLastName();
    }
```

and likewise in your other method, whatever that might be.

Answer (score 1):

for the (object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args) bit put this: (this, new EventArgs())

Answer (score 0):

Since your code doesn't actually use the `sender` parameter you can simply pass in a null.  As for the `ServerValidateEventArgs` you can just new it up, there's no magic.

```
CustomValidatorDelLN_ServerValidate(null, new ServerValidateEventArgs(String.Empty, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you're referring to is an event and it needs to be wired up to your validator either through the html or in a page event. Example:

```
<asp:CustomValidator OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorDelLN_ServerValidate" />
```

or

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomValidatorDelLN.ServerValidate += CustomValidatorDelLN_ServerValidate;
}
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.mobilecontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate.aspx